# Ir al menú principal en Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo el siguiente Navigation Drawer:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que yo quiero es que al ir a cada Fragment no haya un botón de retroceso para volver al Menú principal. Al momento de presionar el Menú Principal quiero que aparezca mi containt main.

¿Cómo se puede hacer eso?

Acá comparto una parte del código del Navigation:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_principal) {
    }
    if (id == R.id.nav_acerca) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new AcercaSMV()).addToBackStack(null).commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_contacto) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new Contactenos()).addToBackStack(null).commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_facebook) {

        Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://es-la.facebook.com/smv.peru/");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(intent);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_pagina) {

        Uri uri = Uri.parse("www.smv.gob.pe");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(intent);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_opciones) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new Opciones()).addToBackStack(null).commit();

    }

    else if (id == R.id.nav_cuenta) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new DatosUsuario()).addToBackStack(null).commit();

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero crea un FragmentMain que al cargar tu actividad principal lo cargues al fragmen como parte de la pantalla (debe ser diferente de tu content_main)
esto dentro del metodo onCreate de tu activity:

```
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new MainFragment()).commit();
```